# How to speed up page load time, Website developed using asp.net(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I developed my website using ASP.Net MVC, While using **Google Page Speed Insight**,
it shows following page load time speed issue.

How to speed up the page load time?

[image: Google Page Speed Insight]

Comment: Are you using IIS to host website? Are you using Entity Framework to connect into database. How about Javascripts, do you have lots of Javascript libraries which are defined in head section of html page?

Comment: i am not using entity framework. i have maintained bundle for javascript and css. and in the head section only two javascripts are binding using bundle.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please use some functionality in coding side

1. Application Caching(where it required [basic tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_caching.htm))
2. Optimize Your Images(use thumbnails if possible)
3. please add Bundling (Bundle/Minify JavaScript/CSS)
4. Use AJAX When You Can
5. For IIS settings please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880900/slow-startup-with-iis-express) discussion
6. Load CSS first and JS in last
7. please CDN for external JS
8. If Using entity framework then use async call and improve performance of sql query

Comment: hi.., i have maintained static caching, and images are also been optimized. bundling has also been performed for minification of JS and CSS

Comment: rather it has taking too much time to load full page

Comment: please suggest any other option, how can i minimize page load time

Comment: please let me know which type of database connectivity you use and other information of page so it will help us get batter idea of actual problem

Comment: if data manipulation is taking time while loading then its better load that data using async ajax method after page load is completed

Comment: basically i used for connectivity of database by ado.net

Comment: please go through  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246251/how-do-i-improve-asp-net-mvc-application-performance